# Nextjs: only home page renders, every other page redirects to home

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes

In my app, all redirects keep going to the homepage. Here is a snippet from my Navbar.js component. I have added the route in the Link tag as is required for next-js. The client and server compile successfully. However the /signup page does not render. Other pages as well do not render.

```js
        <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3 ">
            <Link href="/signup">
              <a className="py-2 px-2 font-medium text-black bg-black-500 rounded hover:bg-black-400 transition duration-300">
                Sign Up
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
```

Here is a snippet from my signup.js page

```js
import { useEffect, React } from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import SignUp from "../components/Signup";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

export default function DefaultSignUp() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <SignUp />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

My SignUp.js component

```js
import React from "react";
const SignUp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-full flex flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <img
          className="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
          src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg"
          alt="Workflow"
        />
        <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
          Sign in to your account
        </h2>
        <p className="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600">
          Or{" "}
          <a
            href="#"
            className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
          >
            start your 14-day free trial
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <div className="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
          <form className="space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Password
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1">
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  required
                  className="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id="remember-me"
                  name="remember-me"
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="remember-me"
                  className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900"
                >
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="text-sm">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
                >
                  Forgot your password?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <div className="mt-6">
            <div className="relative">
              <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center">
                <div className="w-full border-t border-gray-300" />
              </div>
              <div className="relative flex justify-center text-sm">
                <span className="px-2 bg-white text-gray-500">
                  Or continue with
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-3 gap-3">
              <div>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Sign in with Facebook</span>
                  <svg
                    className="w-5 h-5"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  >
                    <path
                      fillRule="evenodd"
                      d="M20 10c0-5.523-4.477-10-10-10S0 4.477 0 10c0 4.991 3.657 9.128 8.438 9.878v-6.987h-2.54V10h2.54V7.797c0-2.506 1.492-3.89 3.777-3.89 1.094 0 2.238.195 2.238.195v2.46h-1.26c-1.243 0-1.63.771-1.63 1.562V10h2.773l-.443 2.89h-2.33v6.988C16.343 19.128 20 14.991 20 10z"
                      clipRule="evenodd"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Sign in with Twitter</span>
                  <svg
                    className="w-5 h-5"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  >
                    <path d="M6.29 18.251c7.547 0 11.675-6.253 11.675-11.675 0-.178 0-.355-.012-.53A8.348 8.348 0 0020 3.92a8.19 8.19 0 01-2.357.646 4.118 4.118 0 001.804-2.27 8.224 8.224 0 01-2.605.996 4.107 4.107 0 00-6.993 3.743 11.65 11.65 0 01-8.457-4.287 4.106 4.106 0 001.27 5.477A4.073 4.073 0 01.8 7.713v.052a4.105 4.105 0 003.292 4.022 4.095 4.095 0 01-1.853.07 4.108 4.108 0 003.834 2.85A8.233 8.233 0 010 16.407a11.616 11.616 0 006.29 1.84" />
                  </svg>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div>
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Sign in with GitHub</span>
                  <svg
                    className="w-5 h-5"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  >
                    <path
                      fillRule="evenodd"
                      d="M10 0C4.477 0 0 4.484 0 10.017c0 4.425 2.865 8.18 6.839 9.504.5.092.682-.217.682-.483 0-.237-.008-.868-.013-1.703-2.782.605-3.369-1.343-3.369-1.343-.454-1.158-1.11-1.466-1.11-1.466-.908-.62.069-.608.069-.608 1.003.07 1.531 1.032 1.531 1.032.892 1.53 2.341 1.088 2.91.832.092-.647.35-1.088.636-1.338-2.22-.253-4.555-1.113-4.555-4.951 0-1.093.39-1.988 1.029-2.688-.103-.253-.446-1.272.098-2.65 0 0 .84-.27 2.75 1.026A9.564 9.564 0 0110 4.844c.85.004 1.705.115 2.504.337 1.909-1.296 2.747-1.027 2.747-1.027.546 1.379.203 2.398.1 2.651.64.7 1.028 1.595 1.028 2.688 0 3.848-2.339 4.695-4.566 4.942.359.31.678.921.678 1.856 0 1.338-.012 2.419-.012 2.747 0 .268.18.58.688.482A10.019 10.019 0 0020 10.017C20 4.484 15.522 0 10 0z"
                      clipRule="evenodd"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SignUp;
```

My _app.js

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url) => {};
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);


  return (
    <div>
      {/* <nav className="border-b p-6 flex justify-between items-center shadow-lg bg-blue-500"> */}
      <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
        <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </RainbowKitProvider>
      </WagmiConfig>
      {/* </nav> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

My next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

/signup route keeps redirecting to the homepage. What can I be doing wrongly?

Comment: Can you please share the code or library used for `<WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>` and `<RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>`

Comment: "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.2.4" , "wagmi": "^0.4.11"

Answer (score 0):

I later found out what was wrong. It might be helpful for someone else but I did two things.

1. Added passHref in my  tag. This way

```js
<Link href="/signup" passHref>
```

2. Also edited my Layout.js to be

```js
  const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div>{children}</div>
        <Footer />
     </div>
  );
};
```